# Cohomology of classifying spaces

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, classifying-spaces

I have studied the Milnor's construction of classifying spaces for classifying vector and principal bundles from the book 'Fibre Bundles' by Dale Husemoller. However this book does not discuss the cohomology of $BG$ & $EG$. Could someone please suggest some good reference for understanding cohomology of classifying spaces ?
At the present instant, I am interested in knowing why the odd cohomology of the classifying space vanishes.

Thanks

Comment: The keyword you want is "characteristic class." It is not true that the odd cohomology vanishes.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Oops, I made a mistake. I should have said the odd cohomology of the total space of the classifying bundle, not the base space. I want to understand this statement in the proof of proposition 3.6 in the Chern-Simons paper https://www.jstor.org/stable/1971013 . Here they consider the classifying bundle in the category of bundles with connections. Also I do not understand what is meant by 'approximation' in the statement 'But since $E$ is an approximation to the $E_G$, its $2l-1$ cohomology vanishes ... ' Could you please explain ? Thanks.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I am really sorry, I again made a silly mistake. $E_G$ is contractible so all its homology groups are automatically trivial. I still do not understand the statement in the Chern-Simons paper, it would be great if yyou could suggest some reference or explain a bit

Answer (score 1):

The odd cohomology of classifying spaces does not vanish in a general case. For example consider $BO(n)$ where its $\mathbb{Z}_2$ cohomology is generated by Stiefel Whitney as a polynomial ring.

You can look at the original paper by Borel-Hirzebruch "Characteristic classes and homogenous spaces", where the cohomology of classifying spaces of Lie groups is described.